# Google App Engine PHP Flexible Env mod rewrite

Tags: php, google-app-engine, mod-rewrite

I have a project structure as attached. I accidentally setup the PHP Flex environment not knowing the consequences that Mod-rewrite would not work as the .htaccess in my project. I want to be able to run the project structure as it is. When i type https://example.appspot.com/ , it should automatically redirect or show the index.php but it keeps show 404 error i guess because the handlers are not defined. Can someone please share with me a app.yaml file with handlers for my structure. I am new to GAE.

```
app.yaml
env: flex
runtime: php


handlers:
- url: /(.+)
  script: mod_rewrite.php (even having this has no effect)
```

Answer (score 0):

App Engine Flex doesn't support mod rewrite it doesn't support the handlers section either.

Where is the `index.php` located? Is it in the project root directory?
If all you want to do is to serve the URL with the `index.php`, you don't have to do anything.

BTW, currently App Engine Flex PHP requires the document_root configuraiton as follows:

```
env: flex
runtime: php

runtime_config:
    document_root: .
```

If your `index.php` is in the project root, it will work. If it's in the subdirectory, use the subdirectory instead of `.`.

Comment: Hi Takashi, I did try all this as well. Index.php is in the root. Finally we removed the mod_rewrite functionality and changed session. Now its fine.

Comment: Good! Can you accept the answer so that the question will be in the `resolved` state?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to remove the mod_rewrite functionality or rather not have it, and there was some sessions issue with PHP 7, and changed that behaviour and it works now.